# MongoDB+Spring: Query Get Object without @DBRef referenceObjects

Tags: spring, mongodb, dbref

I am trying to query object without nested reference using Spring and mongo DB. 
For instance

```
@Document
public class A {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String data;
    @DBRef
    private B b;
}

@Document
public class B {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String data;
}
```

I want to get A object without reference.
Querying A

```
public List<A> getAllA(String id) {
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.all());
    List<A> aList = null;
    aList = mongoOperations.findOne(query, A.class);
    return aList;
}
```

Returns, I don't want to get nested b object:

```
[{
    "_id": "AId..",
    "data": "Adata..",
    "b":{
        "id":"BId..",
        "data":"Bdata"
    }
}]
```

Comment: Why can you not simply ignore `b`?

Comment: When A and B have too nested objects affect querying performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude fields.

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(<query criteria>);
query.fields().exlude("b");
```